# How to sort a SET of strings and store the result

Tags: redis

How do I sort a SET in redis and store the result as a SET and not as a list?

```
sadd myset "a" "b" "g" "w"
sort myset ALPHA STORE myset_tmp
type myset_tmp
> list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You CANNOT do that**. The destination of `sort` must be a `list`.

Also, it doesn't make any sense to store the result into another `set`. The `set` you want, is just a copy of the original `set`. So the `sort` is redundant.